# Raspberry Pi 4: Maximum current for the 5 V/ground GPIO pins

Tags: pi-4

As there are two 5 V GPIO pins (2 and 4), I wonder what the maximum current draw is for each pin. Can I safely power the RPI 4 only using one pin (GPIO 2 + 6)?

Comment: Technically those are not GPIO (general purpose input/output) pins, they just share a breakout with them.   Pretty sure the answer is yes, and there is no point in two pins because they are the same power rail.  However, I have not done this with a Pi 4.

Comment: You are right, GPIO is a digital term! Yes, I also thought so. Even a simple USB-C cable is enought to power it, so the two pins should be enough ...

Answer (score 0):

I have powered the Pi4 from a 5V and ground pin (pins 4/6) of the extension header.

I have had no problems.

However I rarely connect a monitor/keyboard or anything to the Pi's USB sockets so probably am using less than an amp.